# connecting issues when setting 'ExitNodes' in torrc

Tags: configuration, exit-relays, bridge, linux, ubuntu

The Tor connection was unstable so I had to use bridges.Got the bridges from [bridges.torproject.org](https://bridges.torproject.org/) and put in the `torrc` file:

```
UseBridges 1
# This works for Ubuntu Linux, adjust the path according to your platform
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3 exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
Bridge obfs3 ip:port Hex
Bridge obfs3 ip:port Hex
```

*I replaced `ip:port` and `Hex` for privacy reasons. (was it necessary?)*

The Tor was connecting fast and working until added `ExitNodes {US}` at the end of `torrc`. after that every time I run Tor it stops at the 50% of connecting process. here's the related part of the log:

```
[notice] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors
[notice] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit 3 (a General-purpose client 1-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 115151ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 0 guards are live.
[notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
```

How to use bridges and `ExitNodes` simultaneously?

Comment: This seems to be a bug. I created an entry in the bug tracker: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15761

Comment: @JensKubieziel Thank you.I'll check both here and bug tracker for the solution.